# No enemies are shown

Tags: python, pygame

When I run this code, no enemies(zombies) pop up on the screen, but the ninja(player) does(movement also works) and the screen is the right color. I am not getting any errors in the terminal. I am using a raspberry pi, if that helps.I have looked up some answers, but they either produce the same thing, or give me errors. Can you help me?

```py
import pygame
import random
from random import randint
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Zombies')
# player
playerImg = pygame.image.load('ninja.png')
playerX = 260
playerY = 500
playerX_change = 0
playerY_change = 0
# enemy
enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 6

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('zombie.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 535))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 100))
    enemyX_change.append(4)
    enemyY_change.append(30)


# functions and classes
def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))
    

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((0, 154, 23))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY_change = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY_change = 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT or pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0
            if event.type == pygame.K_UP or pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY_change = 0
    # Boundaries
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 536:
        playerX = 536
    if playerY <= 0:
        playerY = 0
    elif playerY >= 536:
        playerY = 536
    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
        if enemyX[i] <= 0:
            enemyX_change[i] = 4
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        elif enemyX[i] >= 536:
            enemyX_change[i] = -4
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]

    playerX += playerX_change
    playerY += playerY_change
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I think you may be missing a call to `enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)` towards the end. I don't know much about pygame but this seems to be how you get the player to render - @Rabbid76 beat me to it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't draw the enemies at all. You have to draw the enemies in a loop. Iterate through the enemies and call the function `enemy(x, y, i)`:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)
```